# Not quite understanding the Q promise library

Tags: node.js, callback, promise

i was looking in to the Q library here: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

This is how i would write a function with a callback:

```
function token(callback) {
    require('crypto').randomBytes(34, function(ex, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        callback(token);
    })
}
exports.generateToken = token;
```

Then i would:

```
require('../models/security').generateToken(function (token) {
    console.log("here " + token)
})
```

How would i do this with a .then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q library works with promises - promises are *resolved* when they're completed with success, or *rejected* when they fail.

In the code you showed us, you can make `generateToken` return a promise for a token, or treat it as a promise in your client code. Both are easy to achieve with Q.

**Returning a promise from a asynchronous task**

```
function token() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    require('crypto').randomBytes(34, function(ex, buf) {
        // reject it if there was an exception!
        if (ex) { return deferred.reject(ex); }

        // resolve it with the correct string value
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        deferred.resolve(token);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Treat `generateToken` as a promise**

```
var generateToken = require('../models/security').generateToken;

var deferred = Q.defer();
generateToken(deferred.makeNodeResolver());
deferred.promise.then(function() {
    console.log("here " + token);
});

// same as above, but with less code
Q.nfcall(generateToken).then(function(token) {
    console.log("here " + token);
});
```

Reading thru the [Q docs](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) you may realize of other ways to achieve the same. I have listed only a few I know will work.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Yes it did, but i am getting this error with the example: Q.nfcall.(generateToken).then(function(token) { SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: the arrow in the CMD is pointing at Q.nfcall.(HERE) as being the point of error

Comment: nvm fixed it, Q.fcall rather then nfcall